# Seeding via Webtorrent not working with webtorrent-hybrid on Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, webtorrent

Software versions:
"webtorrent-hybrid": "^4.0.1",

OS X 10.14.4

NPM: 6.13.4

Node: v8.17.0

```
var WebTorrent = require('webtorrent-hybrid')

var client = new WebTorrent()

client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`fatalError ${err.message || err}`);
  process.exit(1);
});

client.seed('./c5l.mp4', function (torrent) {
  torrent.on('warning', function (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  });
  torrent.on('error', function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  });

  console.log('client.seed done', {
    magnetURI: torrent.magnetURI,
    ready: torrent.ready,
    paused: torrent.paused,
    done: torrent.done,
    infohash: torrent.infoHash
  });
});
```

Gives me my magnet string. On the frontend I have:

```
script(src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webtorrent/0.107.17/webtorrent.min.js')

script.
  var client = new WebTorrent()


// working torrentId
  var torrentId2 = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:c9e15763f722f23e98a29decdfae341b98d53056&dn=Cosmos+Laundromat&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexplodie.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.empire-js.us%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.btorrent.xyz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.fastcast.nz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openwebtorrent.com&ws=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2F&xs=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2Fcosmos-laundromat.torrent'

// failing torrentId
  var torrentId5 = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:f9435fb103d53a0b3cce14afbae867cc6999d76b&dn=c5l.mp4&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexplodie.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.empire-js.us%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openwebtorrent.com'

  client.add(torrentId5, function (torrent) {
    // Torrents can contain many files. Let's use the .mp4 file
    var file = torrent.files.find(function (file) {
      console.log(file);

      return file.name.endsWith('.mp4')
    })

    // Display the file by adding it to the DOM.
    // Supports video, audio, image files, and more!
    file.appendTo('body')
  })
```

When I have the working torrentId the video loads as expected. When I sub it out with the magnet url that was created via the webtorrent-hybrid package I first get some errors:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://tracker.fastcast.nz/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Great, so I remove that tracker from the querystring, try again:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://tracker.btorrent.xyz/' failed: Unknown reason`

Great, remove it again I get something that just hangs and nothing happens.

If I use the magnet on Brave it just hangs at `Loading the torrent file list` and the spinner endlessly spins.

What's going on? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// working torrentId
var torrentId2
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:c9e15763f722f23e98a29decdfae341b98d53056&dn=Cosmos+Laundromat&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexplodie.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.empire-js.us%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.btorrent.xyz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.fastcast.nz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openwebtorrent.com&ws=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2F&xs=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2Fcosmos-laundromat.torrent
```

is/are a well seeded file(s) is means it works 90-100%

```
// failing torrentId
var torrentId5 = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:f9435fb103d53a0b3cce14afbae867cc6999d76b&dn=c5l.mp4&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexplodie.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.empire-js.us%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openwebtorrent.com'
```

is none or low seeded file(s) is means it works 0.1-10%

Answer (score 0):

> When I have the working torrentId the video loads as expected. When I
> sub it out with the magnet url that was created via the
> webtorrent-hybrid package I first get some errors:
>
> WebSocket connection to 'wss://tracker.fastcast.nz/' failed: Error in
> connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
>
> Great, so I remove that tracker from the querystring, try again:
>
> WebSocket connection to 'wss://tracker.btorrent.xyz/' failed: Unknown
> reason
>
> Great, remove it again I get something that just hangs and nothing
> happens.
>
> If I use the magnet on Brave it just hangs at Loading the torrent file
> list and the spinner endlessly spins.
>
> What's going on? Thanks

*WebSocket connection to 'wss://tracker.fastcast.nz/' failed: Error in
connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED*

*wss://tracker.fastcast.nz/* is dead and discontinued to support by the owner in year 2019

*WebSocket connection to 'wss://tracker.btorrent.xyz/' failed: Unknown reason*
is a busy tracker, the response rate is too long and runs in a cheap server due to low funding. so it works 30-90%. so the result is *failed: Unknown reason*

> If I use the magnet on Brave it just hangs at Loading the torrent file
> list and the spinner endlessly spins.

*Webtorrent* clients have some issues downloading/playing large files and unsupported file formats like *.mkv (video/x-Matroska)*. And you can not see any notification if there is an error(s). It just hangs up.